# How to add data to a specific row in Google Sheets using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In my Google Sheet, I have the index in a variable called colorRow. And i'm just trying to add some data to that row in the sheet but the data keeps going to some other row down the page. What am I doing wrong?

```
var data = [];
// Some more fields in data array
data.push("Final Submission Date: " + new Date());
// target_sheet.insertRowAfter(colorRow); // Tried this didn't work
target_sheet.appendRow(data);
```

I need to figure out some way to either reset the append counter so that I can set it to row {colorRow} or if there is a way I can add to a specific row, maybe something like

```
target_sheet.addAt(7, data)
```

Something like this would be ideal.

Comment: What do you mean by the "index in a variable called `colorRow`"?  Why do you have curly braces around {colorRow}  Is it a JSON object, as opposed to an array?

Comment: The curly braces is just to indicate that i'll be using that variable to determine which row should be populated. colorRow is just a row number where the data needs to appear. data is the array which i'm looking to populate.

Comment: `colorRow` should be used in the first parameter of `getRange(start row, start column, number of rows, number of columns)`  You want the data to be set starting at the `colorRow`  So:  `getRange(colorRow, start column, number of rows, number of columns)`  If all the data goes into one row, then `number of rows` would be 1.  But I don't know how your data array is set up.  One problem that sometimes happens, is that the inner arrays have a different number of values in them, but I don't know if that happens with your data. If your data is just a 1D array, and you want 1 row, and each element a

Comment: cell value, then all you need to do is wrap the data in another outer array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use appendRow to do what you want.  You are using:

```
target_sheet.appendRow(data);
```

You need to use `setValues()`

```
target_sheet(start row, start column, number of rows, number of columns).setValues(data);
```

In your case, if you want to overwrite (edit) an existing row, then you will need to find the row with the index in it, and use that number for the `start row` parameter.

```
var data, dataAs1D,dataFromCol1,ouss, target_sheet, lastRow,rowToEdit;

ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('name');

lastRow = target_sheet.getLastRow();

dataFromCol1 = target_sheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow,1).getValues();//Get all col A values
dataAs1D = dataFromCol1.toString().split(",");//Convert 2D array to 1D

rowToEdit = colorRow;//

data = ['one','two','three'];
outerArray = [];//Assign empty array to variable name
outerArray.push(data);
target_sheet.getRange(rowToEdit,1,data[0].length,data.length).setValues(data);
```

This example assumes that your index numbers are in column one.

Comment: I have data as an array. Can I use that directly? If not how do I convert that to an Object? That's been my biggest issue. If I use data array as is for setValues() I get Cannot convert Array to Object[][].

Comment: You can define an outer array, and push the data array into the outer array `var outerArray; outerArray=[]; outerArray.push(data);`  That will be just one row of data.  If your data is not for one row, you will need to probably loop through the data, and create an inner array for each row.

Comment: I have accepted the main answer but pushing the array will not work either. Even row by row will not work. I have had to manually loop through each element and assign manually. Seems like there is no other way to do it more elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this. Solved my problem.

```
var rows = spreadsheet.getRange('A1:b2').activate()

var myData = []
myData[0] = []
myData[0].push(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy"))
myData[0].push("Fake valeu 1")
myData[1] = []
myData[1].push("Fake valeu 2")
myData[1].push("Fake valeu 3")
    
rows.setValues(myData)
```